# looping throught the folder

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I need to solve trivial task running in loop sequence of the commands:

1) to take input .dcd file from the folder
2) to make some operations with the file
3) to save results in list

My code (which is not working !) looks like

```
# make LIST OF THE input DCD FILES 
path="./inputs/"
dirs=os.listdir(path)

for traj in dirs:
  trajectory = command(traj)
```

it correctly define name of the input but wrote that evvery file is empty

alternatively I've used below script to loop through the files using digit variable assidned to name of each file (which is not good in my current task because I need to keep name of each input file avoiding to use digits!)

```
# number of input files
n=3

for i in xrange (1,n+1):
 trajectory = command('./inputs/file_%d.dcd' %(i))
```

In the last case all dcd files were correctly loaded (in opposit to the first example)! So the question what should I to fix in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir()` gives you only the base filenames *relative to the directory*. No path is included.

Prefix your filenames with the path:

```
for traj in dirs:
    trajectory = command(os.path.join(path, traj))
```

Comment: Thank you! one extra question: now if I have list of all my input dcd files in the dirs variable (so e.g dirs[0] would correspond to the 1.dcd etc) is it possible to take that names and use it as the parts of new file names or variables? E.g I need to save some new file ('processed_of_1.txt') which is the result of the  processing of the 1.dcd? How it would be possible to take '1' from dirs and use it as the part of new filename?

Comment: @user3470313: take a look at the [`os.path.splitext()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext); it'll return `('1', '.dcd')` for your filename; use the first element for the new filename.